# Stored Procedures: Which is more similar to SQL Server 2000 - Postgresql or MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2000

I have a SQL Server 2000 database with a lot of stored procedures. I want to migrate to a open source database and well I know I will have to re write the procedures but I would like to do this with as little effort as possible

Answer (score 5):

Neither are a direct port, but of the two -- MySQL's syntax is more similar to SQL Server's than PostgreSQL.

SQL Server 2000 didn't have analytic/ranking/windowing functionality -- neither does MySQL currently.  Also, no WITH/CTE support - again, MySQL doesn't support this either.  If you were migrating away from SQL Server 2005+, I'd have recommended PostgreSQL 8.4+ for the sake of either of the two things I just mentioned.

Comment: Yep, PostgreSQL is much more powerfull and that's what you need when you have to port many stored procedures from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's stored procs are really basic, for instance you cannot raise an exception from within a proc, which makes error handling REALLY PAINFUL. Also, debugging stored procs is a pain, the error messages are unclear, and the language itself is pretty limited.

Postgres is much more mature for this ; if your app has lots of stored procs, this pretty much rules out mysql.

Comment: thanks to all for your responds, I think @peufeu were simple enough for me to take a decision, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL supports stored procedures, per se; PostgreSQL supports stored functions, which are in practice very similar.
>   The first query language for PostgreSQL, PL/pgSQL, is similar to Oracle's PL/SQL. PostgreSQL supports SQL:2003 PSM stored procedures as well as many other general purpose programming languages such as Perl (PL/Perl), Python (PL/Python), TCL (PL/Tcl), Java (PL/Java) and C (PL/C).
>   MySQL follows the SQL:2003 syntax for stored routines, which is also used by IBM's DB2.
>   —MySQL AB , MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 18 Stored Procedures and Functions
>   Via the plugin interface MySQL supports external language stored procedures in Java, Perl, XML-RPC with more language plugins in the works.

from [link text](http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#Stored_Procedures)

Comment: That's great, what are the practical implications of the wall of text you quoted?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting didn't carry over from the original source.  It explains that PostgreSQL is more similar to oracle's pl/SQL.  thought it would be useful to the OP.  The link also provided a lot more comparison between the two backends.